# What is the difference between f/6 in dx and fx lens?

Tags: aperture, sensor-size

What is the difference between f/6 or f/1.8 in dx and fx nikkor lens?

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you asking whether there is a difference in exposure between formats,  or about different lenses on the same body? Or just about what different f numbers actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The f-number is the ratio of a lens's focal length (distance from lens to sensor, roughly speaking) to the diameter of the pupil through which light enters (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-number).

Having said that, there is no difference between f/6 on DX or FX format lenses, as there is no difference between f/1.8 on DX or FX format lenses - the ratio's are the same for each lens type.